# Pass variable PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html

Need to pass variable from actual site like this

```
   <form id="form" action="Atest.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
         name: <input name="name" value=""  id="name" /> <br />
        **<a href='Atest.php?searchname=<?php $_GET['name'];?>'>**GO</a>
  </form>
```

The part searchname= isn t working.

Problem still staying after SET/SET or GET/GET fix
Page throwing :

/Atest.php?    searchname= Notice:%20%20Undefined%20index:%20name%20in%20**C:\xampp\htdocs\PhpProject3\Atest.php**%20on%20line%20**32**

fULL CODE

```
     <?php
      function runMyFunction(){ echo "DONE"; 
            } 
     if (isset($_GET['searchname'])) {
     runMyFunction();
      }




    ?>
 <html><head></head>
   <body>
 <div class="sas">
   <form id="form" action="Atest.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

            Heslo: <input name="name" value=""  id="name" /> <br />
       <a href='Atest.php?searchname=<?php $_POST['name'];?>'>Run PHP Function</a>
        </form></div></body></html>
```

Comment: you are using `POST` as the form method, change that to `GET`

Comment: Can you share the code for `atest.php` ~ at least up untilline 32 where the error is because it is not clear exactly what you are asking if using `GET` as the form method doesn't help

Comment: Line 32  -> <a href='Atest ..........

Comment: that function is not the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The closest I can think you mean is like this:

```
<?php
    function runMyFunction(){ 
        echo "DONE"; 
    }
    if ( isset( $_GET['searchname'] ) ) { 
        call_user_func('runMyFunction');
    }
?>
 <html>
     <head></head>
     <body>
        <div class="sas">
            <form id="form" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                Heslo: <input name="searchname" value="" id="name" /> <br />
                <input type='submit' value='Run PHP Function'>
            </form>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

You could alternatively use a textual link and assign a javascript function to it that submits the form.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this one:

```
<a href='Atest.php?searchname=<?php $_GET['name'];?>'>**GO</a>
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what your code does ?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do this following way:

```
<form id="form" action="Atest.php" method="get" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    name: <input name="searchname" value=""  id="name" /> <br />
    <button type="submit">**GO</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Page refer to itself  so on first visit value is empty

Answer (score 0):

This code will throw you an error. you are mixing POST and GET.

```
<form id="form" action="Atest.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
     name: <input name="name" value=""  id="name" /> <br />
    **<a href="Atest.php?searchname=<?php $_GET['name'];?>">**GO</a>
```

Before you use GET or POST, make sure you check for the value.

```
if(isset($_GET['name']){
        // your stuff here
}
```